# Evaluate the following Limit (CALC I)

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the following limit

$\lim_{x \rightarrow  0} \frac{1}{x^2} * \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t+t^2}{1+sin(t)}$

When I apply the limit I get the indeterminate form $ \frac{0}{0}$ allowing me to use l'Hospital. My book says the derivative of this expression is

$\frac{\frac{x+x^2}{1+sin(x)}}{{2x}}$

The numerator comes from the FTC, but the denominator I don't understand. If I apply product rule get

$\frac{x+x^2}{1+sin(x)}*\frac{-2+x}{x^3} 
\neq \frac{\frac{x+x^2}{1+sin(x)}}{{2x}} $

If I use quotient rule it still does not equal. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that "the derivative of this expression", but that you are taking the quotient of the derivatives of the numerator and the denominator when applying L'Hopital.

In general, when L'Hopital is applicable,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}
$$
**NOT**
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'
$$

The derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$. That is where the denominator is from:

$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow  0} \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t+t^2}{1+\sin(t)}dt
=\lim_{x \rightarrow  0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x} \frac{t+t^2}{1+\sin(t)}dt}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t+t^2}{1+sin(t)}dt= \frac{\int_{0}^{x} \frac{t+t^2}{1+sin(t)}dt}{x^2}.$$